# Graph drawn in the 3D euclidean space with no crossings

Tags: graph-theory

How do i formulate this proof?

Prove that every finite graph can be drawn in the 3D euclidean space with no crossings.

Answer (score 2):

Just pick any point set with no 4 points lying on a common plane. Then clearly there can be no intersections. You can construct such an point set incrementally.